# Clarification on XSLT processing using Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have two simple templates listed below operating on some sample data also listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="Gallery/Tab/ImageGroup/Image">
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="imageText" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="imageText">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="." /></h2>
    </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Gallery name="My Gallery">

    <Tab tabID="imageDivTab0" height="500" name="Team Wear">
        <ImageGroup>
            <Image>
                <imageName>Challenge-Badge.jpg</imageName>
                <imageURL>images/gallery/small/Tab1/</imageURL>
                <imageText>Challenge Badge</imageText>
            </Image>
        </ImageGroup>
    </Tab>

</Gallery>
```

When the processor runs I get the expected result (imageText being displayed) if I comment out the first template I get everything being displayed  (imageName, imageURL and image Text).

Is this because the second template is trying to match 'imageText' without the proper context, i.e. it is using the root node, so it displays everything.

I am fairly new to this so any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: If I remember this correctly the processor searches for a template for the root element, i.e. `/`, but since you do not use a template for the root it will treat all template paths as if they originated from the documents top level element. 

However this does not explain why you get all the content.

Answer (score 1):

There are several built-in template rules.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule

In your case applied templates are:

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: So if it doesn't match, it is just displayed.                        Is that why the 'imageText' is being displayed as an <h2> and the others are just plain text.